# Get more than one ui slider on a document

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

how to get two jquery ui slider on a a page , when i used id slider for than one div only first slider is shown

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    .
            .
            .
            .
            .


            <div id="left_panel">
                <div id="panel_title">
                    Left Panel
                </div>
                <textarea id="txt" >        </textarea>
                <input type="checkbox" name="right_to_left" value="Bike">
                Right to Left
                <br/>
                <div id="font_family">
                    <!--[if !IE]> -->
                    <div class="notIE">
                        <!-- <![endif]-->
                        hello
                        <select>
                            <option>Apples</option>
                            <option selected>Pineapples</option>
                            <option>Chocklate</option>
                            <option>Pancakes</option>
                        </select>
                        <!--[if !IE]> -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- <![endif]-->
                </div>
                <br/>
                 Size:<div class="font_size" class="slider"></div>
            Opacity:<div class="font_opacity" class="slider"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="middle_panel">
                I am in middle

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Please suggest?html

Comment: You need to use different ID's

Comment: Don't you love how jQuery can make people forget the most basic of HTML rules? not just here, but there've been many questions like this.

Comment: Id should be unique or every element, so use different.

Comment: @Kolink i know id, classes but class is not wroking please check

Comment: First, use `<div class="font_size slider">` instead of `<div class="font_size" class="slider">`. This code is... ugh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as many as you want in one page and to  make them work independently you should use uniques selectors and `id` is the best one.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/s225x/) is a fiddle to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

**use by class , don't use with id, id must be unique**

```
 Size:<div class="font_size slider"></div>
                Opacity:<div class="font_opacity slider"></div>
```

Comment: yes i tried giving class ... but when i set class="slider" , first one also don't come

Comment: Two `class` attributes on one element? Groovy.